# ffmpeg handle packet lost during mixing video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to mix several video and audio streams into one big video and then stream it using HLS. What should I do if there are some packets lost during processing, especially in large amount such as 1 or 2 seconds lost. Is there any option that can be used to solve this issue or should I just simply create fake packets/frames to fill the lost ones? I am using ffmpeg api to do this so I can utilize both ffmpeg command-line options and code.
Here is my shortened complex filter for two videos (the full filter is too complex and unnecessary here)

`[0:v] setpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART)  / (TB * 1000000)' [v0]; [1:v] setpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART)  / (TB * 1000000)' [v1]; [v0][v1] xstack=inputs=2:layout=0_0|428_0 [vmixed]; [0:a] asetpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART)  / (TB * 1000000)' [a0]; [1:a] asetpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART)  / (TB * 1000000)' [a1];  [a0][a1] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest [amixed];`

Comment: Share your full ffmpeg cmd.

Comment: Your full cmd, please.

Comment: @Gyan I code. I don't have full command.